# How can I fix the passive voice error in this sentence?

Tags: american-english, passive-voice

> To combat this, new security measures **have been implemented** such as
>   identification checks and on-site police officers.

The error is in bold. I've been reading online about passive voice but every time I come up with a new sentence, it has another passive voice error somewhere else. Thanks.

Comment: I take it you can't say ***we** have implemented* as in *to combat this, we have implemented new security measures such as...*?

Comment: I must be thick, but I do not understand what is wrong in the above mentioned sentence... Or is it that you would prefer to avoid the passive form?

Comment: As has been pointed out, there is no error in the sentence. Whoever told you there was one is ignorant; ignore their grammatical advice if possible. On the other hand, the sentence would be improved if _new security measures_ weren't separated from their examples _such as identification checks ..._. So put them both back together and put the verb phrase at the end: _To combat this, new security measures such as identification checks and on-site police officers have been implemented._

Comment: By the way, here is [an online grammatical description you can trust](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922) of the English Passive construction that covers pretty much everything, by the pre-eminent expert on the subject, Geoff Pullum.

Comment: Can you implement an on-site police officer?

Comment: I suspect it is Microsoft Word that is highlighting the OP's passive voice "errors".

Comment: @Shoe Trusting Microsoft to handle  your grammar for you is about as clever as trusting it to handle your computer for you. Read: ***NOT!***

Comment: @tchrist, John Lawler above mentions the estimable Geoff Pullum and his regular forays about the passive on Language Log. Here is one, entitled [Mass insanity over passive UFOs continues](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2524), in which Pullum not only rants against passive ignorance but also against the evils of Microsoft.

Comment: @Shoe Yep, I’ve read that one before; I think Arnold Zwicky may have referenced it. While I rejoice that no Microsoft heresy has ever  passed the threshold of  that fair and cloistered monastery in which I exclusively dwell, it grieves me that those condemned to the unclean world without must forever suffer vicious violence against their prose, and for no reason. It is a crime against humanity; best call the Hague.

Comment: I have come across this assertion about Passive Voice sentences on many occasions. It happened with almost 100% of cases on MS Word and given some of my other encounters, it leads me to believe that use of the Passive is strongly discouraged in America. Am I right there and if so, can anybody explain why?

Comment: Whoops, I see also now that this has been tagged 'American English'. I guess that supports my assumptions but why is this the case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no grammatical error in the sentence. If you've been told by an English teacher that there is a problem, then they are referring to a stylistic error (according to whatever guidelines they adhere to). It is possible that someone would expect you to use active voice here because the agent of the verb is known. For example, if the sentence is about security at a university:

> To combat this,  the university has implemented new security measures, such as identification checks and on-site police officers.

There are also many people who prescribe that you should (almost) never use passive voice. You might have one of those telling you that your sentence is wrong (which it isn't!).

Comment: I agree with that last sentence. The fashion for short, active sentences everywhere is really annoying.

Comment: It isn't even a stylistic "error." Use of passive voice is not an error at all. Even *Strunk & White*, which inveighs against it, does so even while using it multiple times. Use of the passive voice has been a lifesaver for me on many occasions.

Comment: @Robusto I see no stylistic problem either. But you just know there are teachers out there rapping students' knuckles over this kind of thing because of their notions of how English ought to be used.

Comment: @SigueSigueBen Before paying much attention to ELU, I had never ever realized how much damage these nattering nabobs of negativity, with all their niggling nonsense, were doing to our children. It’s appalling how stupid they are. It’s like Feynman regarding science texts, where he decided they were all dangerous garbage to be thrown out. But they won’t be because of moneyed interests compounded with incredible stupidity/gullibility. Is there a solution?

Comment: @tchris And they would hate that we use conjunctions at the beginning of our sentences.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the passive voice is that we tend to use it excessively. Because it shifts attention to the logical object by making the logical object into the grammatical subject, we do not notice the logical subject (whoever is doing the thing that gets done). Bureaucrats in particular love to use this sort of language because it literally avoids assigning responsibility.

> A decision has been made to close the left lanes of the Beltway during
>   rush hour.

That preceding sentence tidily avoids giving the poor motorists, stuck in traffic, someone specific to hate with an unending and murderous rage. :)

As a technical writer, I have learned to write very precisely. If it is important that the logical subject is unimportant, then I avoid discussing the logical subject and possibly thereby diverting attention.

> Passengers are advised to keep their passports ready.

In the preceding case, it does not much matter who is doing the advising, because it is good advice, and that's the key thing that is to be noted.

To accomplish this sort of writing, the passive voice is best. Otherwise, if the logical subject is important or discussing the logical subject just does not matter, then I use an active voice.

The general drift of *Strunk & White* is to say what you mean and mean what you say, and do so precisely and clearly. To use the example provided with the question, a rewrite might be useful depending on the purpose of the text. If I did not like the security measures in question and wanted everyone to know who is to blame, I would write:

> To combat this, the Administration has implemented new security
>   measures such as identification checks and on-site police officers.

Likewise, I would rewrite the text into the active voice if it were for a news piece and needed to convey the 5 W's and H: who, what, when, where, why, and how. The key thing about the passive voice is that it leaves out a "who". Oftentimes, it feels more formal because doing so creates something of a distance and delay between the reader and the subject, whereas the active voice creates an immediacy and urgency.

So no, the passive voice is not bad grammar, though in many circumstances it is bad form or style - evasive where directness is called for, aloof where immediacy is more appropriate, etc.

Comment: But how do you define "excessively"? Perhaps it's just that a lot of the time, the identification of the subject is spurious.

Comment: +1 for the astute analysis of when passive voice *is* called for.